# Running single Peltier Module at high power vs running multiple peltier Modules at low power? Which is more efficient?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Please give calculation for peak power consumption wrt whichever is efficient.

Comment: Please justify your answer and we can then comment. We are not a free homework service.

Comment: I meant no to show no authority or rudeness, by asking for justification. There ia no need to be salty about it. This is not for homework, and no it's a different question altogether and it does not answer my question

Comment: There are several q&a about peltier on here - have you read them all if not, you should...

Answer (score 0):

A thermoelectric cooling module has a thermal efficiency of some fraction of [Carnot efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_cycle). The [thermoelectric cooling wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling#Performance) puts them at 10 to 15% of Carnot efficiency.

Running themoelectric modules in a series (stacked) configuration would be very disadvantageous as the waste heat also has to be pumped.

Running thermelectric modules in a parallel (side by side) configuration would be advantageous because it would permit more heat transfer surface area on both sides of the module, which gives smaller temperature differences, which gives a higher Carnot efficiency.

Running multiple themoelectric modules in **parallel** is more efficient than a single module for the same energy input.